# Error running Hibernate project in IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.3

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea

I have hibernate project structure  like this
[image]

My hibernate.cfg.xml is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=WSMS</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
        <mapping class="test.IssuesEntity"/>
        <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
        <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My main class is

```
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     /// System.out.print("jajaja");
        Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");//populates the data of the configuration file

        //creating seession factory object
        SessionFactory factory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();

        //creating session object
        Session session=factory.openSession();

        //creating transaction object
        Transaction t=session.beginTransaction();

        IssuesEntity e1=new IssuesEntity();
       // e1.setId(115);
       // e1.setFirstName("sonoo");
       // e1.setLastName("jaiswal");
        e1.setIssueName("akash");

        session.persist(e1);//persisting the object

        t.commit();//transaction is commited
        session.close();

        System.out.println("successfully saved");
    }
}
```

But whenever i run project it shows following error

```
Feb 26, 2016 10:02:59 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
Feb 26, 2016 10:03:00 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.2.Final}
Feb 26, 2016 10:03:00 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Feb 26, 2016 10:03:00 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
```

I have followed intellij instruction but i can not find any solution. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an error. It is just an information that you don't have `hibernate.properties` file in the class path. You have properties in the `hibernate.cfg.xml`, it is ok too. But you need to specify `hibernate.dialect`, `hibernate.connection.username` and `hibernate.connection.password`.

And if you don't have tables in the database you need this too

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Comment: I have added in the hibernate.cfg.xml following the help of this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_configuration.htm and it works .Thanks man for explaination